# What's wrong with this stochastic integral calculation?

Tags: stochastic-integrals

To compute $E[(\int_0^1 W(s) ds)^2]$, I know that using integration by parts and Ito isometry, we have:
\begin{align}
E\left[\left(\int_0^1 W(s) ds\right)^2\right] &= E\left[\left(W(1) - \int_0^1 sdW(s)\right)^2\right]\\
& = E\left[\left(\int_0^1dW(s) - \int_0^1 sdW(s)\right)^2\right]\\
& = E\left[\left(\int_0^1 (1-s) dW(s)\right)^2\right]\\
& = E\left[\int_0^1 (1-s)^2 ds\right]\\
& = \frac13
\end{align}
But what is wrong with the following calculation?
\begin{align}
E\left[\left(\int_0^1 W(s) ds\right)^2\right] &= E\left[\left(W(1) - \int_0^1 sdW(s)\right)^2\right]\\
& = E\left[W(1)^2 - 2W(1)\int_0^1 s dW(s) + \left(\int_0^1 sdW(s)\right)^2\right]\\
&= 1 + E\left[\int_0^1 s^2 ds\right]\\
& = \frac43
\end{align}

Comment: The random variables $W(1)$ and $\int_0^1sdW(s)$ are not independent.

Comment: @UBM, ah... thanks! I got it.